# $(V,\rho)$ irreducible, im $\rho \subset \mathfrak{sl}_n$, then $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

> Let $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ for some finite
>   dimensional vector space $V$, over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$ of
>   characateristic $0$.
>
> Suppose that $\rho: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ and that
>   $V$ is irreducible as a $\mathfrak{g}$ representation. Moreover, for any $x \in
> \mathfrak{g}$, tr$(\rho(x)) = 0$. Then $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple.

My attempt:

I've used Lie's theorem and Lie's lemma to show that $\rho(\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple;

the assumption of irreducibility allows us to conclude that the weight space of some

$\lambda :$ rad$\rho(\mathfrak{g}) \to \mathbb{F}$ is $V$ itself.

From here, since tr$(\rho(x)) = 0$, and since $h(v) = \lambda(h)v$ for any $v \in V$ and any $h \in$ rad$\rho(\mathfrak{g})$, we have that rad$\rho(\mathfrak{g})$ must be zero, since char$\mathbb{F} = 0$.

Is the fact the image is semisimple relevant? How I can go back to the original Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, or am I off track?

Comment: The assumptions are about the image... back to $\mathfrak{g}$, you have the kernel $\mathfrak{n}$ of $\rho$, and so you know that $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}$ is semisimple. Of course it tells you nothing about the structure of $\mathfrak{n}$ itself; yet it at least says that the radical of $\mathfrak{g}$ is contained in $\mathfrak{n}$.

Comment: @YCor do you think there is a mistake in the question? In the question as it is posted it says to assume that $V$ is irreducible as a $\mathfrak{g}$ representation and that tr$(\rho(x)) = 0$ for any $x \in \mathfrak{g}$, Do you think it means to assume that any subspace which is stabilized under $\mathfrak{g}$ itself is trivial or the whole space?

Comment: But being stabilized by $\mathfrak{g}$ or by $\rho(\mathfrak{g})$ means the same...

Comment: @YCor why? And do you have an idea about how to approach this question?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $\mathfrak{g}:=\mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb C)$ which has a one-dimensional centre $\mathfrak{z}$, and let $\rho$ be the compositition

$$\rho: \mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb C) \twoheadrightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb C) / \mathfrak{z} \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C) \subset \mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb C).$$

Maybe what is meant in the question is that the given inclusion $\mathfrak{g} \subset\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ itself is irreducible when viewed as representation? Then you're done if you managed to show that $\rho(\mathfrak g)$ is semisimple.

**Added**: A comment asked to explain how to get semisimplicity. To rephrase what OP says in the question:

Let $R := rad(\mathfrak g)$ the radical of $\mathfrak g$ (i.e. its maximal solvable ideal). Our goal is to show $R=0$. Now, restricting the natural representation to $R$ we have a representation of $R$ on $V$. Assume w.l.o.g. $V \neq 0$. By [Lie's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie%27s_theorem) (applicable since $R$ is solvable) there exists a nonzero vector $v \in V$ and a functional $\lambda: R \rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that for all $r \in R$, $r.v = \lambda(r) \cdot v$.

By what [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784195/96384) calls the "invariance lemma" (which is proven e.g. in step 4 of the Wikipedia article about Lie's Theorem linked above), the space $\{v \in V : r.v = \lambda(r) \cdot v \}$ is not just invariant under $R$, but under the action of all of $\mathfrak g$. (This is the big hammer we need for this -- I admit this is not a trivial result!)

Since we showed above that this space is not $0$, by the irreducibility condition it must be all of $V$. That means that for all $r \in R$ and $v \in V$, $r.v = \lambda(r)v$, i.e. $r$ operates via the scalar $\lambda(r)$, i.e. it must be a scalar matrix. (Compare this part of the proof to [Irreducible action of a solvable ideal in $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$ implies that the ideal has only scalar matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4132002/96384)). But in characteristic $0$, the only scalar matrix with trace $0$ is the zero matrix. So $R$ had to be $=0$ all along.

Comment: Maybe! But can you explain why $\rho (\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple implies the original is as well in that case? I'm not sure I see it:)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "given inclusion ⊂(V) itself is irreducible when viewed as representation? Then you're done if you managed to show that ρ() is semisimple"?

Comment: It's hard to explain if you don't see this immediately. According to the question, $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{gl}(V)$. That is what I mean by "given inclusion". Then if one views this inclusion as a map from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ (sending an element $x$ to itself), it is an injective homomorphism of Lie algebras. Call it $\rho$. You get $\mathfrak{g} \simeq \rho(\mathfrak{g})$. (I am not sure though if this is indeed how the question is meant. Because if it was, one could just say that the traces of elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ seen as elements of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ are $0$.)

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realise you meant that $\rho$ was the inclusion map itself. Then yes of course in that case we'd be done. I need to ask around see what is actually meant here..

Comment: How do you show that $\rho (\mathfrak{g} ) $ is semisimple?

Comment: @Anonmath101: See edit.