# Intuition for the invariance lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, intuition

The invariance lemma, as stated below, is commonly used to prove Lie’s theorem.

> **Lemma** (Invariance lemma). Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field of characteristic zero.
> Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a $\mathbb{k}$-Lie algebra, let $M$ be a finite-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$.
> Let $\lambda$ be an element of the dual space $I^*$ and let
> $$
>   M_\lambda
>   :=
>   \{
>     m \in M
>     \mid
>     \text{$x m = \lambda(x) m$ for all $x \in I$}
>   \}
> $$
> be the corresponding $I$-weight space of $M$.
> This weight space is already a $\mathfrak{g}$-subrepresentation of $M$.

Every time I’m reading through my old notes on representation theory of Lie algebras I’m wondering where this lemma comes from.
I have no intuition for why it should be true, and if I hadn’t seen a proof of it I would probably even suspect it to be false.

> What is the intuition behind the invariance lemma?

Answer (score 3):

This is a slight extension of the idea that for *commuting* endomorphisms $S,T$ of a vector space $V$, the $\lambda$-eigenspace $V_\lambda$ of $T$ is stabilized by $S$. Maybe good to recall the one-line proof: for $v\in V_\lambda$,
$$
T(S v) \;=\; (TS)v \;=\; (ST)v \;=\; S(Tv)\;=\; S(\lambda v) \;=\; \lambda Sv
$$
so $Sv$ is in $V_\lambda$.

In your case, $\lambda:I\to k$, and $\mathfrak g$ does not quite commute with $I$, but stabilizes it. But the proof is essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:** I agree that the Invariance Lemma does not feel intuitive, and I think part of the reason is that it is not true in general characteristic. One needs to use characteristic $0$, but in a rather intricate way. Maybe it helps to first look at the following weaker version, which **is** true in any characteristic, and arguably does feel more intuitive.

**Weak Invariance Lemma**: Let the setup be the same as for the Invariance Lemma, except we allow the base field $k$ to be arbitrary. For every $m \in M_\lambda$ and $g \in \mathfrak g$, let $\langle m \rangle_{g} := \mathrm{span}\{m, gm, g(gm), ... \}$ the subspace of $M$ generated by iteratively applying $g$ to $m$. Then $\langle m \rangle_{g}$ is stable under $I$; in fact, there is a basis of it w.r.t. which the action of each $x\in I$ is given by an upper triangular matrix with all diagonal entries being $\lambda(x)$.

The proof for this is part of all proofs I know for the Invariance Lemma, see e.g. the main parts of step 4 in [WP "Lie's Theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie%27s_theorem) or [Neunhoeffer, Lemma 10.2](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EMax.Neunhoeffer/Teaching/liealg/liealg.pdf). If you're like me, you believe it once one says "$M$ has finite dimension, so use induction with $x(gm) = g(xm) + [x,g]m$, and $I$ is an ideal and acts by scalars on $M$".

The extra bit which upgrades it to the usual Invariance Lemma is that in characteristic $0$, those upper triangular matrices are actually diagonal. Now let's first look at an example in positive characteristic where that is not the case:

**Example 1:** Let $\mathfrak g : = \mathfrak{gl}_2(\mathbb F_2)$ act naturally on $M := \mathbb F_2^2$, and let $I := \{ \pmatrix{a&b\\b&a}: a,b \in \mathbb F_2 \}$. For $\lambda(\pmatrix{a&b\\b&a}) := a+b$, $M_\lambda$ is the diagonal $\{\pmatrix{y\\y}: y \in \mathbb F_2\}$.

Let $m := \pmatrix{y\\y}, g := \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$. Then $\langle m \rangle_g$ is all of $M$, and although $x=\pmatrix{a&b\\b&a}\in I$ acts on the basis $(m, gm)$ via $\pmatrix{\lambda(x)&b\\0&\lambda(x)}$, this is not a diagonal matrix in general. --

Now the joke is that in characteristic $0$, one can upgrade the weak version this to the normal version. For this, let us first reformulate the Invariance Lemma.

Fix $\lambda \in I^*$, and call $I_{0} := \{ x \in I: \lambda(x) = 0 \} = \ker(\lambda)$. It is clear that $I_0$ is a (codimension $\le 1$) ideal of $I$. But with this notation, via $$xg (v) = gx (v) + [x,g] (v) = \lambda(x) g(v) + [x,g] (v)$$ for all $x \in I, g \in \mathfrak g, v \in M$, the invariance lemma is equivalent to:

$$[\mathfrak g, I] \subseteq I_0 \qquad \qquad (*)$$

In particular, $(*)$ implies (but is stronger than saying that) $I_0$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak g$, not just in $I$.

But here's the punchline: We can get $(*)$ from the weak invariance lemma by noticing: All commutators $[g,x]$ ($g\in \mathfrak g, x \in I$) act on that space $\langle m \rangle_g$ with trace $0$ (that's what commutators do), and **in characteristic $0$ that is only possible if** $\lambda([g,x])=0$.

---

**Approach 2:** Besides, there are two special cases of the Invariance Lemma which are true regardless of the characteristic of $k$, and (thus?) probably more intuitive:

**Special Case 1:** $\lambda = 0$. Then, $M_\lambda$ is just the subspace on which $I$ operates trivially (i.e. maps everything to $0$), and that this is stable under all of $\mathfrak g$ follows just from $I$ being an ideal.

**Special Case 2:** $I$ is central in $\mathfrak g$. (Cf. paul garrett's answer.)

Note how $(*)$ is trivial in either of these. But why would it hold in general? Well, in fact it does not, unless we assume the characteristic of $k$ to be $0$. E.g. in example 1 above, $I_0$ is the span of $\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$, and while that is an ideal in $I$ (as always), it is not an ideal in $\mathfrak g$.

---

**Side remark:** Another telling special case might that of one-dimensional $I = (x)$. Here, characteristic $0$ provides us with

**Lemma**: ("In characteristic $0$, ad-invariant elements are central or nilpotent.") Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(M)$. Let $x \in \mathfrak g$ be so that its span is an ideal in $\mathfrak g$, i.e. stable under all $ad_{\mathfrak g}(g)$. Then $x \in Z(\mathfrak g)$, or $x$ is nilpotent as endomorphism (i.e. there is $n$ with $x^n = 0$, w.r.t. the associative multiplication).

*Proof*: If $x \notin Z(\mathfrak g)$ there is $g \in \mathfrak g$ with $[g,x] = rx$ with $r \in \mathbb k^\times$. This implies that all $x, x^2, x^3, ...$ have trace $0$, which in characteristic $0$ implies that $x^n = 0$ for some $n$.

**Corollary:** The Invariance Lemma holds (in characteristic $0$) if the ideal $I$ has dimension $1$. (Namely, we can reduce to at least one of the two special cases from Approach 2.)

Note that with this we could finish the general case by "modding out $I_0$", **if only we knew** that $I_0$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak g$: i.e. we have reduced $(*)$ to the weaker $$[\mathfrak g, I_0] \subseteq I_0 \qquad \qquad (**)$$ But not even this $(**)$ is true in positive characteristic, see Example 1.

But in fact, not even the above corollary holds in general characteristic:

**Example 2:** An ad-stable element which is neither central nor nilpotent, in characteristic $2$.

Let $\mathfrak g : = \{ \pmatrix{a&b\\b&d}: a,b,d \in \mathbb F_2 \} \subset \mathfrak{gl}_2(\mathbb F_2)$. The element $x = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ spans a one-dimensional ideal in $\mathfrak g$, but is neither in $Z(\mathfrak g)$, nor nilpotent as matrix. (Note however that $trace(x^n) = 0$ for all $n$.)

Accordingly, in this example, the Invariance Lemma fails for $M = \mathbb F_2^2$ with the natural representation, $I = (x)$, $\lambda(x) = 1$. For now $M_\lambda = \{(y,y): y \in \mathbb F_2\}$, the diagonal subspace, which is not stable under the full $\mathfrak g$.