Proof of Invariance lemma
I am reading Introduction to Lie Algebra by Kirdman. I had a doubt.

Assume that $F$ has characteristic zero. Let $L$ be a Lie subalgebra of $\text{gl}(V )$ and
let $A$ be an ideal of $L$. Let $\lambda : A \rightarrow F$ be a weight of $A$. The associated weight
space $$V_{\lambda} = \{v \in V : av = \lambda(a)v \forall a\in A\}$$
is an $L$-invariant subspace of $V$ .

Proof: If $y\in L$ and $w\in V_{\lambda}$ then $y(w)\in V_{\lambda}$. That is, to show that $\forall a\in A, a(y(w))=\lambda(a)(y(w))$.
Again, using the above trick, we get $$a(yw)=y(aw)+[a,y](w)=y(\lambda(a)w)+\lambda([a,y])(w)=\lambda(a)yw+\lambda([a,y])(w).$$
So it is enough to show $\lambda([a,y])(w)=0$.
Consider $U=\text{span}\{w,y(w),\dots, y^{m-1}(w)\}$ such that they are linearly independent and hence  $w,y(w),\dots, y^{m-1}(w)$ are basis of $U$.
Claim: Let $z\in A$, then wrt the basis $w,y(w),\dots, y^{m-1}(w)$, $z$ is represented as an Upper triangular matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda(z)$.
Proof: We prove it by induction on columns (from left to right). For our base case, it is true as $zv=\lambda(z)v$. For $yw$, note that $$z(yw) = y(zw) + [z, y]w=\lambda (z)(yw)+\lambda[z,y](w)$$ which is the second column.
Say it is true till $k$ th column.  Hence, $$z(y^{r-1}w)=\lambda (z)(y^{r-1}w)+ u, u \in\text{ span}\{w,y(w),\dots, y^{r-2}(w)\}.$$
So $k+1$th colum will be $$z(y^rw)=zy(y^{r-1}w)=(yz+[z,y])(y^{r-1}w)=yzy^{r-1}w+[z,y]y^{r-1}w$$$$= \lambda (z)(y^{r}w)+ yu+ [z,y]y^{r-1}w$$
Since $[z,y]\in A $, we get $[z,y]y^{r-1}w=\lambda([z,y])y^{r-1}w\in \in\text{ span}\{w,y(w),\dots, y^{r-1}(w)\} $. So induction works.
Now take $z = [a, y]$. Note that the trace of the matrix of $z$ acting on $U$ is $m\lambda(z)$. $U$ is invariant under the action of $a \in A$, and $U$ is $y$-invariant by construction.
Note that trace is $0$. So $\lambda(z)=0$ as char is $0$. So done. We proved it.
But here, I did not get what was the need of stating $U$ is invariant under $a$ and $y$. Please help.



Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784195/96384
