# Irreducible action of a solvable ideal in $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$ implies that the ideal has only scalar matrices

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

> Let $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{gl}(n)$ a Lie algebra with irreducible action on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let $a \subset \mathfrak{g}$ a solvable ideal. Prove that $a \subset \mathbb{C} Id$.

First, I observed that by Lie theorem, modulo a change of basis, $a$ is made of upper triangular matrices. Then, I showed that all strictly upper triangular matrices lead to a subrepresentation of $\mathbb{C}^n$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, so the only possibility is that $a$ is made of only scalar matrices. Is that correct?

I am not sure if I should be more formal in proving that strictly upper triangular matrices lead to $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$: the way I showed it is by observing that any strictly upper triangular matrix when multiplied by a vector in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ always annihilates the last component of the vector.

Comment: One way to formalize the intuition is that the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices has dimension $n^2$; now, the condition of being strictly upper triangular translates into a number of linear conditions on the entries (=coordinates) of a matrix.

Comment: Your approach sounds feasible, but one problem is that while you get a nontrivial $\mathfrak a$-subrepresentation there, it is rather the $\mathfrak g$-action which is supposed to be irreducible, so unless you show more, there's no contradiction. Also, nothing gets "annihilated" in general (maybe you wrongly think of *strict* upper triangular matrices), it's just that a set of upper triangular matrices has an obvious one-dimensional subrepresentation, the vectors with zeroes except in the first coordinate.

Comment: The best (and to be honest, only) way I can think of to prove this is by combining Lie's Theorem (there is $0 \neq v \in V$ on which $a$ acts via a certain linear form) with what this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784195/96384 calls "the invariance lemma": the weight space of $a$ to that form is a $\color{red}{\mathfrak g}$-subrepresentation, so by irreducibility ...