# Proof that if $L \subset \mathfrak{sl}(V)$ then $L$ is semisimple

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am trying to show that if $V$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$, and we have a Lie algebra $L \subset \mathfrak{sl}(V)$ such that  the natural representation $(V, \rho:L \subset \mathfrak{gl}(V) )$ is irreducible,  then $L$ is semisimple.

Not really sure what to do.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your title misses the crucial condition that $V$ is irreducible as representation of $L$. Anyway, what you want is sketched in the question here. They use Lie's Theorem and irreducibility to infer the radical of $L$ is trivial. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3023019/96384

Comment: I saw this post but not sure how to make sense of it all. Would you care to explain or elaborate a little?

Comment: What is not clear, can you also elaborate a little?